# How to know whether a conda downgrade will break conda and the python environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Sometimes, upgrading certain conda packages will lead to downgrade of other conda packages. How does one know whether the downgrade will break conda and the python environment?

I am using python 3.7 and conda 4.8.3

Comment: What do you mean? Conda won't intentionally change package versions in a way that would create incompatibilities. The safest is to specify the packages when creating the environment, and not touch anything after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rule of thumb is to review any proposed changes to ensure that all the builds on the `conda*` packages (right now, `conda` and `conda-package-handling`) always match the Python version. For example, in mine I currently have

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
conda                     4.8.3                    py37_0  
conda-build               3.18.11                  py37_0  
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
python                    3.7.1                haf84260_7
```

where one can see that all the `conda` package build strings have `py37`, which matches my Python version 3.7.*. Were I to upgrade to Python 3.8 without also upgrading the `conda` package to a `py38` build, it would likely break the install.

Personally, I never use my **base** Python as an interpreter, so I find no reason to ever mess with its version. One can always create a new env when that is needed.  However, if you do need to upgrade, I find the safest thing to do is always request both together, e.g.,

```
conda upgrade -n base python conda
```

and **review the proposed changes thoroughly**.